# C# - How to set ID on a specific instance of class

Tags: c#

I am very new to C# so excuse me if i'm asking a silly question.

This is my code:

```
public class SpellsTemplate
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int type;
    public float base_damage;
    public int buff;
    public float buff_debuff_time;
    public int healing;
    public float base_healing;
    public int class_specific;
    public float cooldown;
    public float cast_time;
    public string icon;
    public string game_prefab;
    public float flying_speed;
    public int chain;
    public float chain_distance;
    public int chain_max_targets;
}

public class SpellsHandler
{
    public List<SpellsTemplate> spellsTemplate = new List<SpellsTemplate>();
.......
some other stuff here....
.......

            spellsTemplate.Add(new SpellsTemplate()
            {
                id = Convert.ToInt32(mysqlReader["id"]),
                name = mysqlReader["name"].ToString(),
                type = Convert.ToInt32(mysqlReader["type"]),
                base_damage = (float)mysqlReader["base_damage"],
                buff = Convert.ToInt32(mysqlReader["buff"]),
                buff_debuff_time = (float)mysqlReader["buff_debuff_time"],
                healing = Convert.ToInt32(mysqlReader["healing"]),
                base_healing = (float)mysqlReader["base_healing"],
                class_specific = Convert.ToInt32(mysqlReader["class_specific"]),
                cooldown = (float)mysqlReader["cooldown"],
                cast_time = (float)mysqlReader["cast_time"],
                icon = mysqlReader["icon"].ToString(),
                game_prefab = mysqlReader["game_prefab"].ToString(),
                flying_speed = (float)mysqlReader["flying_speed"],
                chain = Convert.ToInt32(mysqlReader["chain"]),
                chain_distance = (float)mysqlReader["chain_distance"],
                chain_max_targets = Convert.ToInt32(mysqlReader["chain_max_targets"])
            });
}
```

Is there any way i can set ID on the instance of the class ?
Like:

```
spellsTemplate.Add(new SpellsTemplate(Convert.ToInt32(mysqlReader["id"]))
```

And then put the data for the class variables.

Also if this is possible how can i select directly that instance from all the others without foreach?

Is it possible ?

Comment: `"Is there any way i can set ID on the instance of the class ?"` => Setting the `id` value is what this line *should* already be doing: `id = Convert.ToInt32(mysqlReader["id"]),`. Is that not working? Do you want to change it?

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you mean by your first question. Regarding the second (quickly selecting an item by id without foreach), there is a Dictionary class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx designed specifically for that

Comment: Side notes: Having public fields is considered bad practice. You should wrap those into properties (you could add '{get;set;} at the end of each one and have them be converted to auto properties). Second: Do not read or store everything as string, use the native type in the data store and read it back as the native type in the reader.

Comment: Create a constructor that accepts an int in your SpellsTemplate class, and then set you id. For your second question, LINQ is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also work with dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<int, object> spellsTemplate = new Dictionary<int, object>();
spellsTemplate.add(Convert.ToInt32(mysqlReader["id"]), yourObject);
```

And to select direclty you can:

```
spellsTemplate[id];
```

Comment: Thank you. It's looking really nice. But how can i select the class variable for instance like this one `base_damage` ?

Comment: spellsTemplate[id].base_damage;

Answer (score 1):

Write a constructor on your `SpellsTemplate` class. This will force anyone instantiating your SpellsTemplate class to provide certain values (such as ID).

```
public class SpellsTemplate
{
    public SpellsTemplate(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    // Make the setter for the ID property private, so it 
    // can only be set within this class (e.g. in the constructor).
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    // The rest of your properties go here.
}
```

Constructors are a *really* important part of object-oriented programming - please [read up on them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) :)

### EDIT

As to the 2nd question:

> Also if this is possible how can i select directly that instance from all the others without foreach?

If you just want to make the code cleaner, you can write code similar to the following:

```
int myId = 5;
SpellsTemplate mySpell = spellsTemplate.FirstOrDefault(spell => spell.Id == myId);
```

However, this is doing a foreach under the hood.

If you actually care about the performance, you will need to use a data-type like a hashtable or dictionary.